# SgmlReader embedded DTD in Nuget package

Tags: sgmlreader

I reported a couple of days ago abut DTD schema not embeded in nuget package of SgmlReader. 
[The post there](http://forums.developer.mindtouch.com/showthread.php?8895-SgmlReader-NuGet-Package)

But I get a responce then it's embeded and in order to use it I have to set DocType as "HTML"
It still don't work for me, does anybody have the same problems with version 1.8.8 which is delivered by Nuget? (1.8.7 works fine for me)

I decompiled both version using DotPeek and I don's see DTD in 1.8.8 (screenshot attached)

[image]

Comment: It seems like they did something wrong in the latest nuget package (1.8.11).  The Resource name suddenly lacks any prefix.